# Writing an (end-) user documentation

Tags: documentation, users

I am looking for (common / abstract) templates and examples for the (end user) documentation of software. I especially need something for an "Installation Guide", an "Operation Guide" (operation / service / administration of the software), "User Guide" and "training documents". I have googled around, haven't found usable resources.  I am also looking for design guidlines.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the docs for existing software and creating your own outlines/templates from them?

Answer (score 2):

It's a big surprise to me, but Microsoft has finally begun to make good, useful, readable docs available. They live in MSDN and they might give you a handle on how good docs are organized. For example, the section on  [**DLLs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551%28VS.85%29.aspx)  is a good one, I think.

And then you can start  [**here at the top level**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663297%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @SnOrfus: look around for a good example and copy the template.

You know already that almost all end-user documentation just sucks; it's so, so bad: wordy, lots of extraneous BS, full of weasel words -- "it is recommended that," "the user is urged to," all crap like that. Just 90% pure hooey. And, by the way, remember that all of these so-called "user guides" are around 1200 pages long and cost $89.95.

There surely are a few good examples around, though. Kernighan and  Ritchie,  [**C Programming Language**](http://tinyurl.com/6x4b5am) is the best example of a good end-user doc that I know of. It's short; it uses normal, everyday words; it's complete; it's correct. A beautiful work of art, in my opinion, that fits comfortably in 256 pages (first edition).

**A good forum for this question** is  [the **writers' group** on StackExchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com). You'll find discussions of end-user technical docs over there sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The best I have found is tutorials/stories rather than encyclopedias for end user application docs - as opposed to library docs.

Pick some of the most common procedures and detail them step-step.

This is much more useful than the docs which just mirror the online help, which is full of cut-paste entries like "this is the blah button, it activates the blah function"

Comment: You are all over the place, dude.

Comment: @Karlphilip - sorry? It wasn't a very detailed answer but it's a useful point

Comment: @Karlphilip - A language difference. In English "you are all over the place" means your work is unorganised/random/crazy - thought you meant the answer was bad.